# What are the planets that appear in "The Mandalorian" Episodes 1 & 2?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

Across Episode 1 and 2 of "The Mandalorian", it seems that there are three planets visited:

**Planet 1**: The planet where [Din Djarin](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Din_Djarin) (The Mandalorian) captures Mythrol

**Planet 2**: The planet where he meets with Greef Karg to get the new bounty

**Planet 3**: The planet where he recovers the asset (*answered*: [known to be Arvala-7](https://www.starwars.com/databank/kuiil))

---

## *Are the names of planet 1 & 2 known?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Planet 2** where the Mandalorian meets with Greef Karga to get the bounty is revealed as [Nevarro](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Nevarro) in Episode 5 "The Gunslinger" by Fennec Shand,
"Ever been to Nevarro? I hear things didn't go so well there, but it looks like you got off easy."

> Referencing the shootout in Episode 3 between the Mandalorians and the bounty hunters guild.

Edit: Thanks to Mithoron for the Wookieepedia article for **Planet 1** that is now Identified as ["Maldo Kries"](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Maldo_Kreis) in this article from [American Cinematographer Magazine](https://ascmag.com/articles/the-mandalorian)

Comment: Looks there's info now https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Maldo_Kreis